# Defining limits for subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose that we have a sequence $\{a_n\}$ with $a_n\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ for all $n$. What I wonder is that is it possible to define a 'limit' for this kind of sequences?

Of course this 'limit' should make some sense. For example intuitively if $a_n=(\frac{-1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$, then $\lim a_n$ should be $\{0\}$, or if $a_n=(-n,n)$ then $\lim a_n$ should be $\mathbb{R}$, etc. I know that some kind of a limit process of curves is used to define functions that are continuous everywhere but differentiable nowhere or space filling curves. But I couldn't find any formal information about this limit.

My goal is to generalise this limit process to $\mathbb{R}^2$ to define limits for shapes. For example, a well-known proof of that $\pi$ is the ratio of the area of any circle to the square of its radius, includes drawing $n$-polygons inside circle and to limit the areas of these polygons. But maybe it is also possible to define a limit for these compact subsets such that the limit of $n$-polygons inside the circle, as $n$ is increasing, is the circle.

So on, I have no idea on how to define this limit. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: like a filter? ${}{}$

Comment: Are you familiar with the notions of liminf and limsup? These extend in a well-defined way to sequences of sets.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/635373)'s a possible definition.

Comment: Maybe [Kuratowski convergence of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_convergence) or any of the many types of set convergence you can find in [**Set-Valued Analysis**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/081764847X) by  Jean-Pierre Aubin and Hélène Frankowska.

Comment: Say $a_n$ is a sequence of real numbers with $\lim a_n=a$. If we define a new sequence with $b_n=\{a_n\}$, with the definition you suggested it looks like $lim b_n=\varnothing$ (or maybe the limit does not exist?). But I think that this limit definition of subsets should also satisfy the limit properties of real numbers, so $\lim b_n$ should be $\{ a\}$. Do you think that it is possible?

Comment: Oh thank you, I never heard about this Kuratowski convergence and it looks like this is what I look for.

Comment: For other reasons I happened to be looking through [**Topologies on Closed and Closed Convex Sets**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0792325311) by Gerald Beer this past weekend, and this is another book I recommend looking through if you can find a copy (nearby library or use of interlibrary loan).